# ASP.NET MVC 3, Code-First EF: OriginalValues?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

My code seems straightforward:

```
bool rv = false;
var results = from user in Users
            where user.userName.Equals(newUser.userName)
            select user;
if (results.Count() == 0)
{
    this.context.Users.Add(newUser);
    this.context.SaveChanges();
    rv = true;
}
return rv;
```

But this causes a `DbEntityValidationException` with an inner exception value that says:
`OriginalValues cannot be used for entities in the Added state.`

...What does that even mean?  The only thing I can think of is that `newUser` shows a value of 0 for `userID` even though this has a private setter and `userID`, as a primary key, is supposed to be database-generated.  But if *that* were the problem, it would not be possible to simply use `Add()` to insert an object into any EF database ever.  So I'm confused.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help shed some light on this.

ETA: `newUser` is created by the following code in my Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateRegistration(FormVMRegistration newRegistration)
{
    //draw info from form and add a new user to repository
    User newUser = new User();
    newUser.userName = newRegistration.userName;
    newUser.screenName = newRegistration.screenName;
    newUser.password = newRegistration.usersPW;

    bool addSuccess = userRep.Add(newUser);
    ...
}
```

`FormVMRegistration` is just a ViewModel with nothing but string properties, to convey data from the Regiostration form to the Controller.
`userRep` is my User Repository.

Comment: UserId shouldnt really have a private setter as EF will try and put its value into this property on save. This should be public instead

Comment: What's the code before this where newUser gets created?

Comment: @Luke: I was following the example of Freeman and Sanderson, but I changed it to public and am still getting the same exception anyway.

Comment: @emragins, I'm going to edit my post with the code from my Controller that creates the `newUser`.

Comment: Try this code first, are you using EF 4.1 or higher? I've successfully tried this, it's working http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-code-first-walkthrough.aspx

Comment: @Michael, the only obvious difference I see between that and my approach is use of `virtual` before a couple of properties; I've been reading up on this and I'm still not sure what benefit it provides.

Comment: virtual facilitates lazy loading

Comment: I gave all the navigation properties in `User` the `virtual` property, and I am still having this error.  Thanks for your suggestion tho.

Comment: Hrm. By any change do you set newUser with items which already may be referenced by EF?  What happens if you build a new user from scratch (100% new, dummy data)?

Comment: This part of the code is from the Registration form, which is the only place a new User would be created... and when it is created all it has is the username, password, and screen name supplied by the Registration form. No other data comes to it from anywhere. So basically I am creating them with 100% dummy data here. In fact as I mentioned below I refactored the User constructor so that the call to add to the DB will be passed a new User() right as it's called.

Comment: I tried, on a hunch, initializing all the `List` properties for `User` on the off-chance that the error was caused by a null-pointer reference to a `List` that doesn't exist.  No dice.

Answer (score 0):

I think it comes from the fact that you're using the newUser object before it is saved. Try to change this line

```
bool addSuccess = userRep.Add(newUser);
```

to

```
bool addSuccess = userRep.Add(newUser, newRegistration.userName);
```

and then (given passedUserName is a passed name from above) change your linq query to:

```
var results = from user in Users
        where user.userName.Equals(passedUserName)
        select user;
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hi veblock, thank you for your suggestion!  It didn't work.  :(  I refactored `User` so the constructor would take `newRegistration` as a parameter.  That way my repository could add by calling `this.context.Users.Add(new User(newRegistration));`

Answer (score 0):

As near as can be determined, the problem seems to have stemmed from "deep" references to objects, or references to references.  IOW, class Foo made a reference to class Bar which made a reference to class Baz which made a reference to class Foo... and apparently EF doesn't like this so much, because it's not easy to validate.